# React Native has something to use local folders as 'package name'. What is it called?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, package.json

It's kind a strange question, but you can probably help me!

In React Native you can add a `package.json` file to your `config` folder for example with the content:

```
{
  "name": "@config"
}
```

Later on, everywhere in your project (no matter how many folders deep), you can load any config-file using `import http from '@config'`.

Can anybody tell me how this is done, and how this is done? I really want to do this in my own Node.js project :)

Thanks in advance!

Bob

Answer (score 0):

> If you plan to publish your package, the most important things in your
>   package.json are the name and version fields as they will be required.

When you create a new package.json and named it as `{"name": "@assets"}`, Now you are exposing your image dictionary assets as a **`module`**. So your question is answered *-how this is done?*  
And for accessing do this `import Images from ‘@assets/images’`; in components. Read more [here](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Aravind! Am I exposing a dictionary as a module by default (no alternative settings required?). Because I've made such a `package.json` but I'm getting an error `Cannot find module '@config`.

Comment: can you double check the path?

Comment: @Bob can you share your pacjage.json file please. and here is a Ref of mine https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/

Comment: Aravind, I probably wasn't clear that I know that this is working for React Native (I use it myself :)), but I can't get it working for my new clean Node.js project. So React Native must be using some babel-module or whatever to make this working, right?

Comment: I am not sure about that...this is how it works in React Native